# How to test if an emoji is animated in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I want the bot to send an image or gif of an emoji that the user sent, but I can't seem to figure out how to detect if the emoji is animated or not.

```
        var emoji1 = args[0].split(':')
        var emojiID = emoji1[2].split('>')

        const emoji = bot.emojis.get(emojiID);

        if (emoji.animated == true) {
            message.channel.send({
                file: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + emojiID[0] + ".gif"
            });
        } else {
            message.channel.send({
                file: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + emojiID[0] + ".png"
            });
        }
```

but when I run this I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'animated' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try doing

````js
const emoji = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === `${emoji1}`);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using `Regex` for this instead. [Here](https://regexr.com/) is an online editor which can help you build regex

```
    var emojiId = args.join(" ").match(/(?<=<a?:.*:)\d*(?=>)/);

    const emoji = bot.emojis.get(emojiID[0]);

    message.channel.send({
            file: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/" + emojiID[0] + emoji.animated
                    ? ".gif"
                    : ".png"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const emoji = args[0];
  if(!emoji) return message.reply('Please define emoji to search for.');
  const emojiID = emoji.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''); //Using RegEx remove everything that isn't a number.
  const fetch = bot.emojis.get(emojiID); //Grab the emoji
  if(fetch.animated == true){ //If it's aniamted.
    message.channel.send({file: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${emojiID}.gif`});
  }else if(fetch.animated == false){ //If it isn't
    message.channel.send({file: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${emojiID}.png`});
  }else{ //If emoji isn't found
    return message.reply('Emoji not found. :(')
  }
```

Here's what I used:
For replace function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
For nested if statements:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Enjoy <3